# Can users of suitable reputation please be allowed to make small edits?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618921/calling-a-function-from-another-file-in-the-same-directory-in-c/6619119#6619119) on SO a few minutes ago, which was excellent except for one ***critical*** typo:

```
#include "add.c"
int square(int i) {
    return i*i;
}
```

should have been `#include "add.h"`, which, in the context of the post and given the user being targeted, is an important difference.

Instead of just being able to correct it, I was forced to leave a long comment to the OP to correct it.

Sometimes, 1 character in a piece of code is the difference between correct and just plain wrong.

Can high rep users please be allowed to make small edits?

Comment: Um...wha? You have almost 15k rep on SO. Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with @bemace.  Which question was at issue?  Why couldn't you fix it?

Comment: @M. Tibbits: I added the link to the question in question.

Comment: As Jeff mentioned, there is no limit. Have you tried it again with your account logged in? Does it still not work for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're confused.

**Users with 2k+ rep can make whatever edits they want.**

Users from 0 (anonymous) to 1,999 rep can suggest edits which

- require review from other users with 2k+ rep before they are accepted
- must be at least 6 characters.

details at
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: 2k seems like a lot of creds to be able to correct and *improve* questions. As a professional proofreader, who has a score of around 500 on 20 different S.E. communities, I find sad that I can't edit anything under 6 characters...

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'm putting this back as an answer... I thought I was missing something, but possibly you missed the fact that you *can* make edits if you have at least 2000 rep? After experimenting a little to make sure, I couldn't find any edits I wasn't allowed to make so I'm not sure what else it could be.

You should see `link | flag | edit` and probably some other options under the question's tags and probably some others since you're over 10k. Apologies if I'm still missing something and telling you things you already know.

Comment: I have been over 10K for a long time on SO, and I am positive that I have been told on multiple occasions that I'm not allowed to edit something with less than 6 characters.  Maybe I missed the memo when it was changed.

Comment: Tested again - I changed `i` to `I` just fine with no other changes. (then went back and made the rest of the changes, I didn't leave a mess). If that's new I'm not sure when it happened

Comment: The reputation limit must have been changed; I can now do 1 character edits where previously I could not.

Comment: As a non-priveleged user, **I could not edit this question** and change it `int i` to `int j` <-- It responded with the error: `Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because: Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?` (in red)

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey 2k users have always been able to edit whatever they want; the 6 character limit has always been for suggested edits

Comment: @Michael: That is positively no true - I have, on multiple occasions been told something to the effect of " Edits must be at least 6  characters - surely there is something else you can change to improve this post".

Comment: @Software Are you sure you were logged in? Were you on another site where you have less than 2k?